# USB-Stick (Format: FAT) retaining incomplete files

Tags: usb, formatting, fat32

I'm having a problem deleting files from a USB-Stick, which is formatted with [FAT](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Allocation_Table).
I tried transferring files from my Mac to the USB-Stick, and if I remember correctly, removed it from the USB-port before it finished transferring the files. Therefore some files weren't transferred entirely, resulting in this:

[image]

The three bottom folders haven't been transferred completely, hindering me from accessing them. The top two folders contain files, which weren't transferred entirely.

If I try to delete the folders, by simply selecting them and pressing ⌘⌫ it deletes them for about a second, but then they return.
I have tried formatting the USB-Stick:

[image]

...but I get the following error:

[image]

> **Deletion of the following medium has failed**
>   Following error has occurred, while trying to delete the following medium:
>   The medium couldn't be deactivated.

---

Is there any way I can delete the entire content, so I have a completely clear USB-Stick?

Comment: Sounds like you tripped the firmware into locking the device. This is often irreversible, designed to protect existing data in the event of a write error. if you have a Win or nix machine, try formatting on that.

Comment: so I can basically throw the USB-stick away?

Comment: I'd wait to see if someone has a neat trick from terminal etc before doing that - but it's highly possible.

Comment: It is NOT locked. It reads "Schreibstatus: Lesen/Schreiben" (that German for R/W). Does `diskutil reformat /Volumes/Stick` output some more information? Besides "The Ghost Inside" ist ein schon ziemliches gutes Lied ;)

Comment: Are you sure it is FAT not ExFAT?

Comment: @MaxRied - thanks… my German's not all that good ;)

Comment: @MaxRied: "The Ghost Inside" is a band, not a song :D  
And yes, it is FAT at the moment.

Comment: Little bit off topic, but to me it's a song by Broken Bells.

Comment: For me it's a Hardcore band ^^

Answer (score 5):

It seems as if Disk Utility can't lock the device. This is usually because some other process has open handles on a mount point that resides on the drive. As it's an USB pen drive, I guess you already tried plugging and reinserting it. Thing is: As soon as it gets mounted, something immediately seems to request a lock. This MIGHT be Finder. If you want to know which process is responsible for this, execute `sudo lsof /Volumes/Stick` from terminal. This shows you all open handles and their respective owners affecting `/Volumes/Stick`.

Try disabling auto mount. Unfortunately it's a bit complicated.

1. Plug in your supposedly faulty stick. Open a terminal and wait until Finder recognizes the drive.
2. Enter `mount`. You will see something like
   `/dev/disk3s1 on /Volumes/Stick (exfat, local, nodev, nosuid, noowners)`. Note down the first part which refers to the device and the first part in brackets, in this example `/dev/disk3s1` and `exfat`, the filesystem on that drive.
3. Run `diskutil info <device> | grep "Volume UUID"` in terminal, where `<device>` must be replaced with the device you noted down in the second step, so you'll end up with something like `diskutil info /dev/disk3s1 | grep "Volume UUID"`.
4. The output of this command is a UUID. It should read something like `Volume UUID:              03D819D9-49E0-387E-AC9E-2CB54BF0DDD9`
5. Now unplug your USB drive and run `sudo vifs`. If you are not used to `vi` you want to put a `EDITOR=nano` afterwards. Edit the last line of the file making it read `UUID=<UUID> none <filesystem> noauto`, e.g. `UUID=03D819D9-49E0-387E-AC9E-2CB54BF0DDD9 none exfat noauto`. Exit the editor.
6. Now plug it back in. If you done the steps correctly, the drive won't be mounted automatically.
7. Try to format it again using Disk Utility.

Comment: Complicated: yes. Pretty clearly explained too :).

Comment: Thank you! When I have access to the USB-Stick I'll try it (and hopefully accept your answer).

Comment: I'm having a problem running the `sudo` command. The Terminal prompts me to enter my password. I don't have a password set for my computer, so when I log in I only press `ENTER`. But when I simply press `ENTER` for the password in the Terminal, it says it's incorrect. Why?

Comment: Are you sure you don't just have auto login enabled? If so, you have to have a password set. Have a look at Systemeinstellungen->Benutzer und Konten. Set one for this procedure.